# PyTorch - How to get the gradient of the first layer relative to the input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, hook, pytorch

With my understanding, by using backward hooks the gradient input at index 0 gives me the gradient relative to the input. This works with all layers, except the first one. In this one, the value at index 0 is None.

Can someone explain how to get the gradient realtive to the input image in PyTorch?

The PyTorch Docs for backward hooks  and an example: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_backward_hook
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nnft_tutorial.html#forward-and-backward-function-hooks

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to set .requires_grad_() for my input data. Now I get the gradients and not None. :D